# Redirecting on confirm true

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I want to make it so the user clicks a link, they get a confirm box. If they click OK, they get sent to a new php function.

I've tried:

```
function confirmReset() {
 var r = confirm('Are you sure?');
 var url = window.location.pathname;
 var pathArray = url.split('/');
 var host = pathArray[1];
 var newHost = '/headquarters/designReset';

 if (r == true) {
    window.location = host + newHost;
    //document.location.href = '/headquarters/designReset';
 } else {
    alert('it didnt work');
 }
 return false;
}​
```

Firebug error says:

SyntaxError: illegal character
}â€‹

It's saying that â€‹ is after the } at the end of the function. I'm getting this script externally so if you post an answer make sure it works externally. Not just in the html file itself. Ive had answers that dont. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `string` method. It gives an error. Also consider adding `return false` to your function in order to prevent the default link action.

*HTML:*

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirmReset();">Test</a>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function confirmReset() {
    var r = confirm('Are you sure?');
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var pathArray = url.split('/');        // <-- no need in "string()"
    var host = pathArray[1];
    var newHost = '/headquarters/designReset';

    if (r == true) {
        window.location = host + newHost;
        //document.location.href = '/headquarters/designReset';
    } else {
        alert('it didnt work');
    }
    return false;                          // <-- add this line
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xKhaq/

Comment: Now when i click the link nothing happens. You should know i am getting the js externally, not in the html file itself.

Comment: @DylanButh What errors do you get in the console? Have you checked the demo? Does it work for you?

Comment: @DylanButh Seems that after some bracket `}` in your code you have invisible symbol that breaks the script. Find and remove the symbol and the code will work.