# Confirm message for delete

Tags: php

This is the confirmation message, but it was not working.

```
While ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$row['counter']."</td>
        <td>".$row['sender']."</td>
        <td>".$row['recipient']."</td>
        <td>".$row['compName']."</td>
        <td>".$row['phonenumber']."</td>
        <td>".$row['department']."</td>
        <td>".$row['subject']."</td>
        <td>".$row['description']."</td>
        <td>".$row['date_request']."</td>
        <td>".$row['date_done']."</td>
        <td>".$row['status']."</td>
        <td>".$row['remark']."</td>
        <td><a onClick=\"return confirm('Sure To Remove This Complaint ?');\"
            href='operator_view_message_del.php?counter=".$row['counter']."'>
            DELETE</a></td>
    </tr>
    ";
```

below is the process of delete

```
if(isset($_GET['counter']))
  {
    $counter=$_GET['counter'];
    $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM complaint WHERE counter='$counter'");
    if($query)
      {
      header('location:operator_view_message.php');
      }
  }
```

I have working link delete a row from my database. what I am looking to do is instead of having a link I want to have a button that when I pressed it bring up confirmation and then delete the row if true.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: You don't have a condition in your onClick method. If you pressed confirm or cancel it will still delete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862786/redirecting-on-confirm-true

Comment: There doesn't seem to have a problem, it will echo `<td><a onClick="return confirm('Sure To Remove This Complaint ?');"
            href='operator_view_message_del.php?counter=test'>
            DELETE</a></td>`

Comment: What you're looking for is *A*synchronous *J*avascript *A*nd *X*ml (AJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with condition

```js
function confirmation(counter) {
  if (confirm('Are You Sure ?')) {
    alert(counter);

    // window.location.href = 'location?counter=' + counter
  }
}
```

```html
<a onClick="confirmation('counter-45')" href='#'>DELETE</a>
```

or use this
https://jsfiddle.net/quetzalarc/br1j0gca/3/